# replace value in php array with given index

Tags: php, arrays, replace

I have a problem on replacing a value in array with exact given index. To be exact, I'd like to replace a string in array[2] with a new number but I don't have an idea. So please have a look on my resources :

```
pos:0 //position of index in array 
id:498 //id of a field
new:6300 //new value to replace in an array
cost:6200-5200-4600-5600-4100 //the array
```

From above, I'd like to replace a string indexes "0" in "cost" with a new string from "new" so the expected result should be :

```
6300-5200-4600-5600-4100
```

I tried to search for everywhere but there's nothing return but array_search - which is not what i'm looking for. Please advise.

Comment: How is you array look? What you has here is not much as PHP code, but normal if you has a array you can access/replace a value by use `$array[$index] = $newvalue;`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$pos = 0;                            // position
$new = 6300;                         // new value
$cost = '6200-5200-4600-5600-4100';  // string
$cost = explode('-', $cost);         // make it array
$cost[$pos] = $new;                  // change the position $pos with $new
$cost = implode('-', $cost);         // return new $cost
// 6300-5200-4600-5600-4100
```

Comment: @Mihai lorga
I've tried your code which seems to be clearest. But the result is a bit weird - the value added up. It becomes six arrays instead of five. Here's the code:`code

room_rate_updatez.php?rate|502|6200-5200-4600-5600-4100|3=5500
foreach($_GET as $key=>$_val){
 list($_name,$_id,$_cost,$_pos)=explode("|",$key);

 $cost = explode('-', $_val);         // make it array
 $cost[$_pos] = $_cost;                  // change the position $pos with $new
 $cost = implode('-', $cost);         // return new $cost

 echo "new cost : ".$cost; //new cost : 5500-6200-5200-4600-5600-4100
}`

Comment: But it should be `$cost = explode('-', $_cost);`

Comment: @Mihai
I've got it. My fault. I confused my own var - swap between $cost and $new so the the array doesn't understand where to replace. Regards,

Comment: Easy. Good job, buddy.

Answer (score 1):

It's so simple:

```
<?php

$array = array(
    6200, 
    5200, 
    4600, 
    5600, 
    4100
);

$pos = 0;
$new = 6300;

$array[$pos] = $new;

?>
```

Comment: This is your first post. So it came under [beta review - first posts](http://stackoverflow.com/review/). To review it we have to edit, vote, flag the post. I found no fault in your post. So just edited and checked it as fine. :)

Comment: And instead of updating it again as old, you can use [rollback function](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/18876/187824) to undo edit.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'm new here and didn't know about "rollback function" ... :)

Comment: You need to visit [Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/) to know more about [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```php
$the_array[$pos] = $new
```

Comment: Added syntax color - but no color appeared... :)